# Bokeh interactive dashboard can not remove lines from plot

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, dashboard, interaction

I am working on my first python Bokeh interactive dashboard. Plot default shows lines for group=a and group=b. When check box[1], plot will add lines for group=a1 and group=b1. When uncheck [1], line a1, b1 are supposed to be removed from plot, but they still stay in the plot.

Below is my sample data and sample code. It can directly run in your jupyter notebook. Can any one help me out?  Thank you very much!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook, push_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CategoricalColorMapper, HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, Panel
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, Slider, RangeSlider, Tabs

from bokeh.layouts import column, row, WidgetBox
from bokeh.palettes import Category20_16

from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.palettes import Category10


output_notebook()

data=[['a',1,0],['a',2,1],['a1',1,0],['a1',2,2],['b',1,0],['b',2,3],['b1',1,0],['b1',2,4]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['group','time','rate'])


def modify_doc(doc):


    def update(attr,old,new):

        temp=[]
        for i in selection1.active:
            for b in selection2.active:
                temp.append(selection1.labels[i]+selection2.labels[b]   )

        to_plot=temp

        for i in range(len(to_plot)):
            source = ColumnDataSource(
             data={'x':df.loc[df.group == to_plot[i]].time,
                   'group':df.loc[df.group == to_plot[i]].group,
                   'y':df.loc[df.group == to_plot[i]].rate})

            p3.line(x='x',
                    y='y',
                    source=source,
                    legend=to_plot[i],
                     color = (Category10[10])[i])


    selection1=CheckboxGroup(labels=['a','b'],active=[0,1]  )
    selection1.on_change('active',update)   
    selection2=CheckboxGroup(labels=['1'] )
    selection2.on_change('active',update)


    to_plot=['a','b']
    p3 = figure()
    for i in range(len(to_plot)):
        source = ColumnDataSource(
        data={'x':df.loc[df.group == to_plot[i]].time,
                   'group':df.loc[df.group == to_plot[i]].group,
                   'y':df.loc[df.group == to_plot[i]].rate})

        p3.line(x='x',
                    y='y',
                    source=source,
                    legend=to_plot[i],
                    color = (Category10[10])[i])   


    controls=WidgetBox(selection1,selection2)

    layout=row(controls,p3)
    tab=Panel(child=layout,title='test')
    tabs=Tabs(tabs=[tab]) 
    doc.add_root(tabs)

handler=FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
app=Application(handler)

show(app)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the problem (which you already corrected) was with the underscore in this line:

```
temp.append(selection1.labels[i]+ "_" + selection2.labels[b])
```

Which should be, of course:

```
temp.append(selection1.labels[i] + selection2.labels[b])
```

So you were referencing `a_1` in the source (which doesn't exist) instead of `a1`.

I felt free to improve your code to also hide the lines if you unselect the checkboxes. This code is for a Bokeh server v1.0.4 but should also work for Jupyter Notebook after removing the marked line block and uncomenting commented lines)

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, Panel, Tabs, WidgetBox, Row
from bokeh.palettes import Category10

data = [['a', 1, 0], ['a', 2, 1], ['a1', 1, 0], ['a1', 2, 2], ['b', 1, 0], ['b', 2, 3], ['b1', 1, 0], ['b1', 2, 4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['group', 'time', 'rate'])

def modify_doc(doc):
    lines = []

    def create_plots(to_plot):
        for i in range(len(to_plot)):
            source = ColumnDataSource(
            data = {'x':df.loc[df.group == to_plot[i]].time,
                   'group':df.loc[df.group == to_plot[i]].group,
                   'y':df.loc[df.group == to_plot[i]].rate})

            lines.append(p3.line(x = 'x',
                                 y = 'y',
                                 source = source,
                                 legend = to_plot[i],
                                 color = (Category10[10])[i]))
            p3.legend.click_policy = 'hide'

    def update(attr, old, new):
        for i in [0, 1]:
            if i not in selection1.active:
                lines[i].visible = False
            else:
                lines[i].visible = True

        if selection2.active:
            if len(lines) < 3:
                temp = []
                for i in selection1.active:
                    lines[i].visible = True
                    for b in selection2.active:
                        temp.append(selection1.labels[i] + selection2.labels[b])
                create_plots(temp)
            else:
                for i in range(2, 4):
                    if (i - 2) in selection1.active:
                        lines[i].visible = True
                    else:
                        lines[i].visible = False
        elif len(lines) > 2:
            for i in range(2, 4):
                if (i - 2) in selection1.active:
                    lines[i].visible = False

    selection1 = CheckboxGroup(labels = ['a', 'b'], active = [0, 1], width = 40)
    selection1.on_change('active', update)
    selection2 = CheckboxGroup(labels = ['1'], width = 40)
    selection2.on_change('active', update)

    p3 = figure()
    create_plots(['a', 'b'])

    controls = WidgetBox(selection1, selection2, width = 40)
    layout = Row(controls, p3)
    tab = Panel(child = layout, title = 'test')
    tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab])
    doc.add_root(tabs)

# handler = FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
# app = Application(handler)

#########################################################################

io_loop = IOLoop.current()
server = Server(applications = {'/myapp': Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))}, io_loop = io_loop, port = 5001)
server.start()
server.show('/myapp')
io_loop.start()

#########################################################################

# show(app)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  now the line can be added/removed from the plot (exactly what I need), but the legend always show 'a, b,a1,b1'. Can you please also make the legend change accordingly with lines ?  Really appreciate it !.

Comment: I move **p3.legend.click_policy = 'hide'** to the right place and now the legend gets muted when you uncheck the boxes

Comment: Thank you, Tony!  Is there any way to remove the line, instead of hiding it?

Comment: Removing glyphs is not officially supported. It isn't impossible but seems tricky to me as you can mess things up easily. If you want remove or add a legend then you could use p3.legend[0].items.pop() and p3.legend[0].items.append(LegendItem(label = 'label', renderers = [renderer])) but I wouldn't do that.

Comment: how do you record  playing with the bokeh dashboard as shown in the result above?

Comment: On Mac I use Quick Time Player (File => New Screen Recording)  to record a short video and then I use FFMPEG to convert it to a GIF image. FFMPEG is not standard included on Mac so you will need to install it. The FFMPEG command is: `ffmpeg -i input.mov  -r 10 -pix_fmt rgb24  -f gif - | gifsicle --delay=8 > output.gif`