# How to record playing interactive dashboard so as to show to others

Tags: python, bokeh, dashboard

In many interactive dashboard posts on internet,writers record how they play the dashboard so as to show to readers like the result at the end of the post:
[Bokeh interactive dashboard can not remove lines from plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445655/bokeh-interactive-dashboard-can-not-remove-lines-from-plot)

How to do it?

I am making a interactive dashboard and would like to record it so as to show it to others.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with bokeh or python, it just seems like they use a screen recorder to create a gif.  I personally use [peek](https://github.com/phw/peek)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Mac you could use Quick Time Player (File => New Screen Recording)  to record a short video and then use e.g. FFMPEG to convert it to a GIF image. FFMPEG is not standard included on Mac so you will need to install it. The FFMPEG command is:

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -r 10 -pix_fmt rgb24 -f gif - | gifsicle --delay=8 > output.gif`

Where `input.mov` is your screen recording and `output.gif` your final GIF animation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several products out there to do this. When I am recoding Visual Studio work for my students, I use Camtasia.  Lookup Video screen recording software and see what you find that you like.